# Let $f(x)=x^n$. Show that $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = x^n$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I was going to expand out a formal definition of derivation, and hope that the left hand side can look like the right hand side. The fact that this needs to be for all $x$ suggests to me that I should be thinking Induction, however I can't find the correct setup.

Comment: Induction isn't necessary. Have you tried using the definition? **Edit:** If you want to use induction, note that $x^{n+1}=x\cdot x^n$ and use the product rule.

Comment: @GitGud If he is trying to prove something this basic, I doubt the product rule is something he is allowed to call on.

Comment: I tried using $|f'(x)|= |\frac{f(x) - f(x+h)}{x+h-x}| $, but I normally continue this route with an analysis of the limits. Not sure how to use it here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start from the definition:

$$
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}h^k-x^n}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^n+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}h^k-x^n}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}h^k}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\displaystyle\binom{n}{1}x^{n-1}h+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}h^k}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left[\displaystyle\binom{n}{1}x^{n-1}+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}h^{k-1}\right]\\
&=nx^{n-1}.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition $f'(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{(x+\varepsilon)^n-x^n}{\varepsilon}$
Since $(x+\varepsilon)^n-x^n= n \varepsilon x^{n-1}+ \varepsilon^2 \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} \varepsilon^{k-2}x^{n-k}$
We get $f'(x)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} (n x^{n-1}+ \varepsilon \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} \varepsilon^{k-2}x^{n-k})$
And finally $f'(x)=n x^{n-1}$